# How can I use R to generate an orthogonal Latin Square given this property?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, generator, algebra

I will do my best to explain the math- if you need any further clarification, please let me know.

Let q be a prime number, theta be a generator of a cyclic group, and i=1,...,q-1.

I want to create a square using this general pattern:

```
(0)                (1)                 (2)                 (x)                (1+x)              ...  (a_(q-1))
(0)+theta^(0+i)    (1)+theta^(0+i)     (2)+theta^(0+i)     (x)+theta^(0+i)    (1+x)theta^(0+i)   ... (a_(q-1))+theta^(0+i)  
(0)+theta^(1+i)    (1)+theta^(1+i)     (2)+theta^(1+i)     (x)+theta^(1+i)    (1+x)theta^(1+i)   ... (a_(q-1))+theta^(1+i)
(0)+theta^(2+i)    (1)+theta^(2+i)     (2)+theta^(2+i)     (x)+theta^(2+i)    (1+x)theta^(2+i)   ... (a_(q-1))+theta^(2+i)
(0)+theta^(3+i)    (1)+theta^(3+i)     (2)+theta^(3+i)     (x)+theta^(3+i)    (1+x)theta^(3+i)   ... (a_(q-1))+theta^(3+i) 
...                ...                 ...                 ...                ...                ...
(0)+theta^(q-2+i)  (1)+theta^(q-2+i)   (2)+theta^(q-2+i)   (x)+theta^(q-2+i)  (1+x)theta^(q-2+i) ... (a_(q-1))+theta^(q-2+i)
```

A few things to note here. I chose arbitrary elements (0), (1), (2), (x), (1+x), etc. that belong to a finite cyclic group of order q^p, where q is a prime number. The elements in this cyclic group, say F[x], are polynomials of up to degree (p-1), with coefficients ranging from 0-(q-1). In fact, the coefficients, and thus the polynomials, are under (mod q).

I have been attempting to build my own algorithm to create a square using this pattern. Assuming that I have a generator (which I have yet to figure out how to code in), I can run the following to obtain each element of the above square. (Note that I am storing the matrix elements in a list because each element in the matrix is actually a polynomial.)

```
F <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lapply(1:p, function(i) 1:q-1L))) #obtains all possible combinations of polynomials up to degree p-1 under (mod q)

polylongdiv <- function(n,d) { #I found this online
    gd <- length(d)
    pv <- vector("numeric", length(n))
    pv[1:gd] <- d
    if ( length(n) >= gd ) {
      q <- c()
      while ( length(n) >= gd ) {
        q <- c(q, n[1]/pv[1])
        n <- n - pv * (n[1]/pv[1])
        n <- n[2:length(n)]
        pv <- pv[1:(length(pv)-1)]
      }
      list(q=q, r=n)
    } else {
      list(q=c(0), r=n)
    }
  }
  gen <- c(0,1) #Since I was testing this algorithm for the case q=2,p=2, the generator of F_8[x] is 0 + x, or c(0,1)
#ideally, I would like to determine the generator in this algorithm rather than calculating by hand

  LS <- list()
  i <- 1 #in case you are curious about the math, we can generate q-1 unique Latin Squares using this technique

  for(i in 1:(q^p)){ #for the first row, we just have each element; this seems to work fine
    LS[[i]] <- F[i,]%%q
  }

  for(k in (q^p+1):q^(2*p)){ #this provides the right dimension for the Latin Square
    for(i in 1:q^p){ #this is where things don't work anymore
      for(j in 0:(q-2)){
        LS[[k]] <- (F[i,] + gen^(j+sub))%%q
      }
    }
  }
```

You may notice that I included a polynomial long division algorithm. This is because the elements' polynomials in the Latin Square cannot exceed degree p-1. (Ex: after applying the general pattern when p=2,q=2,i=1 and generator 0+x, the third row, column column element would be 1+x^2, but we cannot have a polynomial of degree 2. So, we use polynomial long division to find out that x^2=1+x under (mod2). This seems like the trickiest part to implement into this algorithm for me.)

Comment: Since this is a diffucult case: can you break down your task in a few simple questions?

Comment: @MartinGal I tried to clean things up in this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552804/how-can-i-construct-a-matrix-given-a-generator-for-this-cyclic-group. Is this better?